# XDEBUG not working properly, but is installed and log says "Connect to client :-)"

Tags: docker, xdebug

xDebug is installed, logs are enabled, validation is fine, logs tell me that xdebug can connect to client; however - no connection to IDE

- installed xDebug with PHP7 in Docker
- added corresponding ini files to the envrioment
- set a breakpoint
- verify xDebug in CLI and FPM

20-xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.55.0.20
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value=PHPSTORM
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/html/htdocs/var
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value=PHPSTORM
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/var/www/html/htdocs/var
xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/html/htdocs/var/log/xdebug.log
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
```

I've installed Docker with PHP7 FPM Module and xDebug. I've installed it with `pecl install xdebug`.

xdebug is being loaded in FPM and CLI, I have placed the corresponding file in the fpm and cli folders properly. I can verify that it loads.

I have enabled the log and am having this blocks inside it:

```
Log opened at 2019-02-08 08:12:24
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/htdocs/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.0.24-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="16" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.6.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2019-02-08 08:12:24
```

So, logstell me that there is a succesful connection.

In PHPStorm I've set up DBGp:
IDE Key: PHPSTORM
Host: 172.55.0.1
Port: 9000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could You try to outcomment or delete `xdebug.remote_host=172.55.0.20`. Because with `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` it should by connected to the remote client. But it didn't know, if it works with docker.

Comment: I'll try to remove and check, but: from the docs can be obtained that the directive `remote_connect_back` is overriding remote_host and checks for HTTP_X_FORWARDED Ip to connect to the client instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line shows the problem

```
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000.
```

Its trying to remote connect back to `127.0.0.1` which inside the container will be the container itself, rather than your machine host. The remote host is ignored when connect back is on:

> This setting is ignored if xdebug.remote_connect_back is enabled.

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host

You should disable `remote_connect_back` and specify the remote host explicitly:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: Should I replace docker.internal with something? Because docker.internal cant be resolved from my containers when I try to ping them.

Comment: This did it. I replaced docker.internal with the IP i did get when finding out the hosts IP inside a docker container - its now connecting perfectly fine. Thank you!